# iOS orientation change resizing

Tags: ios, uitableview, orientation-changes

I have read a lot of SO question about this already but nothing seems to work in my case. Simply when you add a UITableView and you test it and rotate the screen it will keep the width of the portrait orientation.

How can I make it so that it will always fill the screen's width for any screen size?

[image]

EDIT : My size inspector

[image]

Comment: Did you try to set `tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight` ?

Comment: I did nothing happened

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Autosizing feature in Storyboard for your `UITableView`. How to set it:

1.Select your `UITableView`.

2.Open the right pane -> Size Inspector:

[image]

3.Scroll down to the View section, here you'll see the Autosizing menu:

[image]

4. Don;t forget to disable Autolayout feature:

[image]

Comment: Where can I find this and how do I set it?

Comment: Go to File inspector (that's the first section of the right pane) and disable Autolayout feature. See updated answer.

Comment: Although I did not changed anything about the autosizing thing disabling auto layout fixed my problem

Comment: How can I do that programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

You're using AutoLayout in your XIB, so the AutoResizingMask stuff isn't your best route to success. You need to set the autolayout constraints on your TableView so that there is a 0 px gap between the leading (left) and trailing (right) sides of the TableView and its superview.

You can see from your screenshot that you already have some constraints in place, but they're probably not correct. I suggest you start by resetting all the existing constraints: I find that's usually best when I've got confused about where I am with constraints.

1. Select the top level view in your XIB file
2. Select `Editor -> Resolve Auto Layout Issues -> Clear All Constraints in View` from the menu
3. Select your TableView
4. Select `Editor -> Resolve Auto Layout Issues -> Reset to Suggested Constraints` from the menu

If that does the trick for you, I'd advise that you spend some time getting familiar with AutoLayout and review the constraints generated: you can select and edit them in the size inspector. [This](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2) is also a pretty good tutorial.

For custom views, I often add my constraints programmatically as it's really easy to keep track of them - they're much more visible than when they're built in IB. I use a set of categories, provided by another SO user, that you'll find [here](https://github.com/smileyborg/UIView-AutoLayout) and they make the code very easy to read and maintain.